# "GenerateMatrix" equivalent command in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy, maple, maxima

In Maple there is a command "GenerateMatrix" that will take a collection of linear equations and generate a symbolic matrix A and symbolic vector b in "Ax=b" where "x" is a vector of variables specified by the command. The help page can be found here if this isn't clear:

http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=LinearAlgebra%2FGenerateMatrix

In Maxima a similar operation can be accomplished using the "augcoefmatrix" command. Is there a similar command in SymPy? How could this command be implemented if the command does not exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SymPy analog is [linear_eq_to_matrix](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#linear-eq-to-matrix). Usage example:

```
from sympy import *
variables = symbols('x y z')
equations = [3*x-z+2, y-3*z-5, x+y-z]
A, b = linear_eq_to_matrix(equations, variables)
linsolve((A, b), variables)
```